# How to assign Column Results to Parameters of a Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table "Values"  The data looks like this:

```
    ID     Label     Value

    1     StartDate  1/1/17
    2     EndDate    1/15/17
    3     Dept         6
```

What I'd like to do is load the values of the "Label" column to the corresponding Parameters in my Query:

```
    Declare 
    @startdate Datetime,
    @enddate Datetime,
    @DepartmentID int

Select * 
From Customers 
Where created between @startdate and @enddate and @DepartmentID
```

How can I assign @Startdate to the 'Startdate' 'value' in the value table?  Additionally, Since i'm using different datatypes in my query, than what they are stored in the Values table (Values are 'nvarchar' in values table) Will I run into potential problems?

Comment: if your values are nvarchar, you have to cast those to date and then check accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare 
@startdate Datetime,
@enddate Datetime,
@DepartmentID int

set @startdate = (Select convert(datetime,[Value]) from dbo.Values where Label='StartDate')
set @enddate = (Select convert(datetime,[Value]) from dbo.Values where Label='EndDate')
set @DepartmentID =(Select convert(int,[Value]) from dbo.Values where Label='Dept')

Select * 
From Customers 
Where created between @startdate and @enddate and DepartmentId = @DepartmentID
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to do something like this:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    CUSTOMERS
WHERE
    CREATED BETWEEN 
        (SELECT TOP 1 [Value] FROM Values WHERE Label = 'StartDate') --perform casts here if necessary
        AND
        (SELECT TOP 1 [Value] FROM Values WHERE Label = 'EndDate')   --perform casts here if necessary
```

Comment: I upvoting, but conversion between strings and dates might be a problem.